# Eclipse: How to overwrite resources in src folder

Tags: eclipse, file-io, path

I have a program that alters a file in my `src/resources` folder, but the file that gets selected is in the `bin/resources` directory. How can I tell Eclipse to modify the file in the `src/` directory. I understand that the bytecode is executed from the `bin/` directory and the file needs to be visible to that folder, but I would like to know if it is possible to reference the `src/` file.

I am using:

```java
File file = new File(MyClass.class.getResource("resources/test.xml").getPath());
```

to load my file, but I don't want the path to my `bin/` directory.

The path is:

```bsh
/C:/Users/Foo/workspace/MyProject/bin/resources/test.xml
```

Comment: MyClass.class.getResource("../src/resources/test.xml") ?

Comment: `SEVERE: File does not exist: ../src/resources/test.xml`

Comment: try to think again if you actually wants to modify the source file.  It rarely make sense.  Most, if not all, code/resource generators avoid touching the actual source code, and only generate/modify sources/resources in output folder.  Your code shouldn't read files in source folder too, as in real execution, there is no such folder

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to view the changes to the file in Eclipse. I could just open up the file through the operating system file browser, but that is annoying and there is no `bin/` directory in the Package Explorer.

Comment: Seems like the requirement is just for your local dev environment. IF yes, use the absolute file path. ( ex- c:/app/myfile.txt)

Answer (score 0):

If you add `src/resources` to Eclipse Build Path, the compiler will then copy the entire folder structure to your output directory (i.e. bin) in which case you refer to `test.xml` using the same code:

```
File file = new File(MyClass.class.getResource("resources/test.xml").getPath());
```